# Conversão de JSON para uma lista de objetos

Tags: json, delphi, genéricos, rtti

Estou com um problema que na realidade não sei se é possível ser feito da forma que eu quero.
Estou tentando criar uma classe que converta um JSON e retorne um lista de objetos, porém de forma dinâmica, para que eu possa efetuar o processo com qualquer classe.

***Exemplo do JSON***

```
[{"id":1,"nome":"Banana Prata","descricao":"Banana Prata", "precos":[{"id":1, "preco":5.50},{"id":2, "preco":6.50}]},{"id":2,"nome":"Banana D'água","descricao":"Banana D'água", "precos":[{"id":1, "preco":5.50},{"id":2, "preco":6.50}]}]
```

***Exemplo da classe***

```
  TPreco = class
  Strict private
  private
    Fid: Integer;
    Fpreco: Currency;
    procedure Setid(const Value: Integer);
    procedure Setpreco(const Value: Currency);
  public
    property id: Integer read Fid write Setid;
    property preco: Currency read Fpreco write Setpreco;
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

  TProduto = class
  Strict private
    // A ordem das variáveis influenciam na consulta dos tipos via RTTI a partir das properties
    Fid: Integer;
    Fnome: String;
    Fdescricao: String;
    procedure Setdescricao(const Value: String);
    procedure Setid(const Value: Integer);
    procedure Setnome(const Value: String);
  private
    FListasPreco: TObjectList<TPreco>;
    procedure SetListasPreco(const Value: TObjectList<TPreco>);
    function GetListasPreco: TObjectList<TPreco>;
  public
    property id: Integer read Fid write Setid;
    property nome: String read Fnome write Setnome;
    property descricao: String read Fdescricao write Setdescricao;
    property Precos: TObjectList<TPreco> read GetListasPreco
      write SetListasPreco;
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;
```

***Classe que faria a conversão***

```
  TJSONEntity = class
  private
  protected
  public
    function JsonToEntity(const AEntity: TClass; const AJson: String)
      : TObjectList<TObject>;
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

function TJSONEntity.JsonToEntity(const AEntity: TClass; const AJson: String)
  : TObjectList<TObject>;
var
  LContext, LContextAux: TRttiContext;
  LType, LTypeAux: TRttiType;
  LProperty: TRttiProperty;
  LInstanceType: TRttiInstanceType;
  lList: TObjectList<TObject>;
  I, J: Integer;
  LPropertyName, LFieldTypeName: String;
  LFieldValue: Variant;
  LJSONArray, LJSONArrayAux: TJSONArray;
  LJsonValue: TJSONValue;
  LCountArray: Integer;
  LOpenBracket, LCloseBracket: Integer;
  LValue: TValue;
  LListAux: TObjectList<TObject>;
  LListPointer: Pointer;
  LFlagSubList: Boolean;
  LClass: TClass;
begin
  Result := nil;
  LCountArray := 0;
  LContext := TRttiContext.Create;
  LType := LContext.GetType(AEntity);

  if Assigned(LType) then
  begin
    LInstanceType := LType.AsInstance;

    LJsonValue := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(AJson);
    if LJsonValue.TryGetValue<TJSONArray>(LJSONArray) then
      LCountArray := LJSONArray.count;

    if LCountArray <= 0 then
      Exit(Nil);

    lList := TObjectList<TObject>.Create;
    try
      // Criar instancias de acordo com a quantidade de objetos do array
      for I := 0 to Pred(LCountArray) do
        lList.add(LInstanceType.MetaclassType.Create);

      try
        for I := 0 to Pred(Length(LType.GetProperties)) do
        begin
          LProperty := LType.GetProperties[I];
          LPropertyName := LProperty.Name.ToLower;
          LFieldTypeName := LType.GetFields[I].FieldType.ToString;

          LFlagSubList := False;

          for J := 0 to Pred(LCountArray) do
          begin
            case LType.GetFields[I].FieldType.TypeKind of
              tkString, tkLString, tkWString, tkUString:
                LFieldValue := LJSONArray.Items[J].GetValue<String>
                  (LPropertyName, '');
              tkInteger:
                begin
                  LFieldValue := LJSONArray.Items[J].GetValue<Integer>
                    (LPropertyName, 0);
                end;
              tkInt64:
                LFieldValue := LJSONArray.Items[J].GetValue<Int64>
                  (LPropertyName, 0);
              tkFloat:
                LFieldValue := LJSONArray.Items[J].GetValue<Double>
                  (LPropertyName, 0.0);
              tkClass:
                if LJSONArray.Items[J].TryGetValue(LPropertyName, LJSONArrayAux)
                then
                begin
                  // Pega novo array de objetos
                  LFieldValue := LJSONArrayAux.ToJSON;
                  // pega tipo da classe contida em TObjectList
                  LOpenBracket := Pos('<', LFieldTypeName);
                  LCloseBracket := PosEx('>', LFieldTypeName, LOpenBracket + 1);
                  LFieldTypeName := Copy(LFieldTypeName, LOpenBracket + 1,
                    LCloseBracket - LOpenBracket - 1);

                  LContextAux := TRttiContext.Create;
                  LTypeAux := LContextAux.FindType(LFieldTypeName);

                  if Assigned(LTypeAux) then
                  begin
                    LClass := LTypeAux.AsInstance.MetaclassType;

                    // TESTE 1
                    LListAux := JsonToEntity(LClass, LFieldValue);
                    LListPointer := @LListAux;
                    TValue.Make(LListPointer, LTypeAux.Handle, LValue);
                    // Não funciona - Invalid Type Cast
                    LProperty.SetValue(lList[J], LValue);

                    // TESTE 2
                    LListAux := JsonToEntity(LClass, LFieldValue);
                    // Não funciona - Invalid Type Cast
                    LProperty.SetValue(lList[J], TValue.From(LListAux));

                    LFlagSubList := True;
                  end;
                end;
            else
              LFieldValue := LJSONArray.Items[J].GetValue<String>
                (LPropertyName, '');
            end;
            if not LFlagSubList then
              LProperty.SetValue(TObject(lList[J]), TValue.From(LFieldValue));
          end;
        end;

        Result := lList;
      except
        if Assigned(lList) then
          lList.Free;
        raise;
      end;
    finally
      LContext.Free;
      LContextAux.Free;
      LJsonValue.Free;
    end;
  end;

end;
```

Uma breve explicação do que o método faz. Bom, basicamente eu uso RTTI para ler a estrutura de uma classe, crio a quantidade de objetos de acordo com a quantidade de itens do array do JSON, e baseado no nome das propriedades e no nome das chaves do JSON, recupero o valor do campo e vou alimentando os objetos da lista de objetos.

O problema é quando eu tenho uma lista de objetos dentro da classe. A ideia era fazer de forma recursiva a chamada do método, porém como preciso de algo genérico, ao efetuar o TValue.SetValue, ocorre erro na conversão devido ao objeto esperar o tipo **TObjectList< TPreco >** e eu estar passando o tipo **TObjectList< TObject >**.

Existe alguma saída para isso? Tentei com Generics, mas acabo esbarrando no mesmo problema, pois para o Generics, preciso passar de forma explicita o tipo da classe, é não é o propósito aqui. Não quero que o método tenha ciência do tipo da classe dentro dele.

Cheguei a fazer alguns testes com os métodos da unit Rest.JSON (TJSON.JsonToObject, TJSON.ObjectToJsonString), mas aparentou resolver da forma que eu quero.

Agradeço a todos.

---

**EDIT**

Com a ajuda da unit Rest.JSON e Pkg.Json.DTO, consegui resolver o problema, não da forma que eu imaginei, porém resolveu.

[Site para a conversão de JSON para Classe Delphi (Pkg.Json.DTO)](https://jsontodelphi.com/)

**Segue a solução:**

```
TJSONEntityHelper = class
private
public
  class function GetList<T: Class, constructor>(const AJSONArray: String): TObjectList<T>;
end;

class function TJSONEntityHelper.GetList<T>(const AJSONArray: String): TObjectList<T>;
var
  LListEntity: TObjectList<T>;
  LArray: TJSONArray;
  LValue: TJSONValue;
  LJsonObject: TJSONObject;
  LEntity: T;
begin
  Result := nil;
  try
    LListEntity := TObjectList<T>.Create;
    try
      LArray := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(AJSONArray),0) as TJSONArray;
      for LValue in LArray do
      begin
        LJsonObject := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(LValue.ToJSON) as TJSONObject;
        try
          LEntity := TJSON.JsonToObject<T>(LJsonObject);
          LListEntity.Add(LEntity);
        finally
          LJsonObject.Free;
        end;
      end;
      Result := LListEntity;
    except
      if Assigned(LListEntity) then
        LListEntity.Free;
      raise;
    end;
  finally
    LArray.Free;
  end;
end;
```

```
uses
  Pkg.Json.DTO, System.Generics.Collections, REST.Json.Types;

{$M+}

type
  TPrecos = class
  private
    [JSONName('id')]
    FId: Integer;
    [JSONName('preco')]
    FPreco: Currency;
  published
    property Id: Integer read FId write FId;
    property Preco: Currency read FPreco write FPreco;
  end;

  TProduto = class(TJsonDTO)
  private
    [JSONName('descricao')]
    FDescricao: string;
    [JSONName('id')]
    FId: Integer;
    [JSONName('nome')]
    FNome: string;
    [JSONName('precos'), JSONMarshalled(False)]
    FPrecosArray: TArray<TPrecos>;
    [GenericListReflect]
    FPrecos: TObjectList<TPrecos>;
    function GetPrecos: TObjectList<TPrecos>;
  protected
    function GetAsJson: string; override;
  published
    property Descricao: string read FDescricao write FDescricao;
    property Id: Integer read FId write FId;
    property Nome: string read FNome write FNome;
    property Precos: TObjectList<TPrecos> read GetPrecos;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation

{ TProduto }

destructor TProduto.Destroy;
begin
  GetPrecos.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TProduto.GetPrecos: TObjectList<TPrecos>;
begin
  Result := ObjectList<TPrecos>(FPrecos, FPrecosArray);
end;

function TProduto.GetAsJson: string;
begin
  RefreshArray<TPrecos>(FPrecos, FPrecosArray);
  Result := inherited;
end;
```

**Exemplo de uso**

```
var
  LList: TObjectList<TProduto>;
begin
  LList := nil;
  try
    LList := TJSONEntityHelper.GetList<TProduto>(Memo2.Text);
  finally
    if Assigned(LList) then
      LList.free;
  end;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Eu faço um uso semelhante:

```
uses
 REST.Json, {sua classe}, System.JSON;

var
  item :Tproduto;

begin
  item := TJson.JsonToObject<TProduto >(Trim(json.ToJSON)); //se a classe tiver igual ao json;
end;
```

//se quiser transformar a classe em json

```
function TProduto.toJSON: string;
begin

  var json  := TJson.ObjectToJsonObject(Self);
  var aux   : string;
  aux       := json.toJSON;
  json.DisposeOf;

  Result := aux;
end;
```

Comment: No meu caso eu quero retornar uma lista de objetos, pois no JSON pode haver um array de objetos e dentro de determinado objeto haver outro array de objetos.

Comment: Mas então, se sua classe tiver bem mapeada funciona, faz uma classe que tem um array de TProduto. Eu tbm faço uso de array dentro de array e funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Consegue mostrar um exemplo?

Comment: é basicamente o que vc fez com a classe preco dentro de produto, so que pode colocar a classe classe produto dentre de outro superior, se eu entendi bem o seu problema

Comment: Fiz um exemplo baseado em um pouco do seu esclarecimento